# Formatting currency within a method?

Tags: java

```
public String toString() //toString withing Shiftsupervisor class
{
    String employee = name + ", " + iD + ", " + hireDate + ", $" + AnnualSal + ", $" + ProdBonus;
    return employee;
}
```

in main:

```
ShiftSupervisor supervisor1 = new ShiftSupervisor("John Smith", "123-A", "11-15-2005", 48000, 6500);

System.out.println(supervisor1);
```

I already added the "$" in my toString but I want this to output the last 2 doubles as 48,000 and 6,500 << adding in the commas!

Could I do this in my setMethods??

Comment: i'm sorry, I don't understand what the requirement is

Comment: If I were you, I might consider whether or not it's feasible to store your currency amounts as integers(representing cents, for instance 200 is $2.00).  It might not be feasible to do that if you're doing certain kinds of arithmetic on those numbers, but doing so will make the numbers more concrete, and make the string manipulation easier.

Comment: If you found a good answer to your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the check under the up/down arrows next to the answer body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Use [`NumberFormat#getCurrencyInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance%28%29) that already handles this for you. Here's an example:

```
NumberFormat cnf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
System.out.println(cnf.format(48000)); // prints $48,000.00
```

If you want to omit the decimal part, just use [`NumberFormat#setMaximumFractionDigits`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits%28int%29):

```
NumberFormat cnf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
cnf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
System.out.println(cnf.format(48000)); // prints $48,000
```

Implementing this in your method:

```
NumberFormat cnf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
String employee = name + ", " + iD +
    ", " + hireDate +
    ", " + cnf.format(AnnualSal) +
    ", " + cnf.format(ProdBonus);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Could I do this in my setMethods?

Yes, you can, but you don't want to.  Trust me on this one.

Usually, you keep the raw values (int, double, float) in your class, and format them in the get methods.  This allows you to format your class output in different ways for different needs.